# Chrome Extension: Unable to pass message to content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from background.js to content.js. 
`addListener` in content.js is not working.

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
{ 
    console.log(tab.url);
    if(changeInfo.status=="complete"){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            if(tabs.length!=0){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "sendurl"}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.url);
                });
            }
        });
        console.log("load complete");
    }
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "sendurl" ) {
      var firstHref = $("a[href^='http']").eq(0).attr("href");

      console.log(firstHref);
      sendResponse({url: firstHref});
    }
  }
);
```

**manifest.json**

```
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/","http://*/"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.js","enc-base64-min.js","hmac-sha256.js","content.js"]

    }
  ],
```

After some tme, it gives error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

Comment: I generally find it easier to send messages from content scripts to background scripts instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"matches": ["https://*/","http://*/"],` only specifies the domain wildcard which means that content scripts are injected for the main page only. The error message you see occurs because `sendMessage` timeouts after some time as there was no content script to receive the message.

As [the match pattern documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) says:

> `http://*/*`   Matches any URL that uses the http scheme

The correct code would be `"matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],`

P.S. Make use of [the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging), it's immensely helpful to catch such errors.